# zip 2D array for parallel iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have the following list of list:

```
x = [['a','b'],
     ['c','d'],
     ['e','f']]
```

I would like to be able to zip the two elements of each list.

At the moment I'm using this solution :

```
for i,j in zip(*list(map(list, zip(*x)))):               #(zip(*transpose(x)))
  print('{},{}'.format(i,j))
```

And I get the following output:

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

But it look unnecessarily complicated. Is there a simpler solution ?

I'm not using something like this:

```
for row in x:
  print('{},{}'.format(row[0],row[1]))
```

Because each column correspond to a specific things and I would like to be able to name this two things: `for food, price in zip(x):`...

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You aren't really doing anything here.  for i in x: print(','.join(i)) works just as well

Comment: cant you just use `[print(F"{food},{price}") for food, price in x]`

Comment: `zip(*)` is `transpose` so you are double transposing which is doing nothing

Comment: Hooooo ! I'm a python begginer, I didn't know that we can directly extract the different element like that ! Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply:

```py
for i, j in x:
  print('{},{}'.format(i, j))
```

You don't need the zip at all. The for-loop will already unpack your 2-array into i and j.

This is similar to `i, j = [1, 2]`; Python automatically unpacks the iterable into variables for you. It's not zip that is doing the work here, zip simply merges arrays together.

Comment: OP mentioned he needs to store name of each column.

Comment: @mathfux, no it's ok, I just need to be able to use a custom variable name like `i` and `j`.

Comment: The name is being stored in "i" and "j". You can change those to "food" and "price" if you want to.